# UIImagePickerController iphone5 Orientation Landscapemode

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-5

i sub classed `UIImagePickerController` and implemented it into `@implementation`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

its works fine but the problem is:

while capturing in landscape mode the display appears in portrait mode and after capturing, the captured image displays correctly(landscape mode)

why is there a change in the display orientation

my code is listed here:

```
@interface NonRotateUIImagePickerViewController:UIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

@end

@implementation NonRotateUIImagePickerViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}


@end
```

before:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=eb7f2f7c40e359ee#cid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE&id=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!493

after:
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=eb7f2f7c40e359ee#cid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE&id=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!492

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the autorotate properties of the view's parent.

This is because if they are set to autorotate, all the children will rotate as well.

Comment: if i set to autorotate value is yes application will crash.

what we can do with above code.